# How to listen all outgoing sms in Android (API 20 to 28)

Tags: android

I am developing android app which detect outgoing sms and save into room database. I target new android versions from API 22 to 28.
For incoming sms I am used receiver(RECEIVE_SMS) . But for outgoing sms I try with ContentResolver class. But it is not guaranteed that work. Sometimes not working.

I run it from mainActivity:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (!hasReadSmsPermission()) {
            showRequestPermissionsInfoAlertDialog();
        }

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms"), true, new SmsObserver(new Handler(), getApplicationContext()));

        SetAlarmPeriodically.schedulePeriodic();
    }
```

and use onbootreceiver to restart ContentResolver

```
public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @SuppressLint("UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver")
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        JobManager.create(context).addJobCreator(new MyJobCreator());
        SetAlarmPeriodically.schedulePeriodic();
    }
}
```

onRunJob

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    protected Result onRunJob(@NonNull Job.Params params) {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ContentResolver contentResolver = getContext().getContentResolver();
                contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms"), true, new SmsObserver(new Handler(), getContext()));
            }
        });

        return Result.SUCCESS;
    }
```

But it is not worked after reboot phone. How can I listen all outgoing sms everytime after app installed? Any guaranteed solutions?

Comment: Registering that `ContentObserver` probably will not work on Android Q and higher, unless your app is the user's chosen messaging client. It also will not work as soon as Android terminates your process, as you are doing nothing to keep your process around. And, if you were planning on distributing this app through the Play Store, it may be rejected.

Comment: I know that. I am using only in one phone not in play store. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Use a foreground `Service`, rather than jobs or alarms.